# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi im trying to create a relation one-to-many in my rails app.

Fist i create my models

```
class Produto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :compra, :descricao, :estoque, :venda

  has_many :precos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :precos
end

class Preco < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :compra_decimal, :produto_id, :venda_decimal

  belongs_to :produto
end
```

Then i created my controller

```
class ProdutosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @produto = Produto.new
    @produto.precos.build
  end

  def create
    @produto = Produto.new(params[:produto])

    if @produto.save?
        redirect_to produtos_path
    end
  end
end
```

After this i created my .html.erb pages:

**_form**

```
<%= form_for @produto do |f| %>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :descricao %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :descricao %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :compra %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :compra %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :venda %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :venda %>
 </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :estoque %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :estoque %>
 </p>
<%= f.fields_for :precos do |builder| %>
 <%= render "precos", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
 <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

**_precos**

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :venda_decimal %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :venda_decimal %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :compra_decimal %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :compra_decimal %>
</p>
```

**new**

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

then, when i submit the form this error appears:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ProdutosController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: precos_attributes
```

does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your model:

```
class Produto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :compra, :descricao, :estoque, :venda, :precos_attributes

  has_many :precos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :precos
end
```