# My model relationships are not working as predicted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got two models that have a certain relationship to each other.

I have a *meal* model and a *meal_food* model.

Here they are as I have them written at the moment:

```
class MealFood < Food
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meal
end  

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :meal_food

  attr_accessible :user_id
end
```

Whenever I attempt to create a meal_food for a meal like so:

```
 meal.meal_food.create()
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: meal_id
```

If I pass in something like this:

```
meal.meal_food.create(meal_id:meal.id)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: meal_id
```

What I expect is to have a meal_food created and have it associated with the meal it was created for. Although, it can have many meals. So I would expect that if I query meal.meal_food it would return all the foods which are associated with that meal. The fact that rails is asking me for a meal_id makes me think that rails thinks this is a one-to-one relationship and the relationship table isn't being created.

---

I've created an Join table. Here's the schema for it:

```
create_table "meals_meal_food", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer "meal_id"
   t.integer "meal_food_id"
end
```

I've also changed my meal model to be like so:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meal_foods

 attr_accessible :user_id
end
```

Error now is:

```
meal.meal_food.create()

>> NoMethodError: undefined method `meal_food' for #<Meal id: 1, user_id: 1>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't updated your models yet, this won't work until you do. Also Rails is convention over configuration which means you have to use the right conventions if you want the Rails "magic" to work. For example your join table should be `meals_meal_foods`, and you should use `meal.meal_foods.create` - plural at the end for both.

Comment: Thanks. the plural part is spot on. I got to a different error here after adding the 's'. :) I must run a migration for the table name change now. Lets see what happens.

Comment: it was actually supposed to be rename_table :meal_foods_meals but you basically helped me get the right idea! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure which one would go first alphabetically, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know your `has_and_belongs_to_many` association is wrong, you need to have it in both models:

```
class MealFood < Food
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
end  

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meal_foods
end
```

Also, the model needs to be pluralized, [have a look at this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association).

You would then need to create a `meal_foods_meals` join table with `meal_id` and `meal_food_id` integer columns.

Then to access your associations you must use the plural form:

```
meal.meal_foods.create
```

If you want use `has_many` / `belongs_to` insead you would still need to pluralize the `has_many`

```
class MealFood < Food
  belongs_to :meal
end  

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meal_foods
end
```

Comment: alrighty. I've updated my question to include working through the first part of your answer. The 2nd part won't work for me because the meal foods should be able to belong to many meals instead of just one. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Answer is in the comments below the question unless mind.blank edits this answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Just change your model to this:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :meal_food

  attr_accessible :user_id, :meal_id
end
```

Note: exact duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799720/activemodelmassassignmentsecurityerror-with-nested-attributes).

Comment: That gives this error "ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: meal_id"